# PHP и 31 марта, вычисление даты месяц назад

Tags: php

Добрый день, у меня странный вопрос:

Есть код:

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('2016-03-31');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d')."\n";

$date->sub(new DateInterval('P1M'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d')."\n";
```

В результате получаю:

```
2016-03-31
2016-03-02
```

Хотя по логике вещей должен получить:

```
2016-03-31
2016-02-29
```

Для даты 2015-03-31 (прошлый, не високосный год)
получаю:

```
2015-03-31
2015-03-03
```

Хотя по логике вещей должно быть:

```
2015-03-31
2015-02-28
```

Что я делаю не так?
Проверял на PHP5.5 и PHP7.0

На всякий случай: TZ=Europe/Moscow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3602421/1016033

Comment: Так это баг или фича, то есть мне для 31 марта по другому вычислять смещение? Есть документация по "магическим датам"?

Comment: Это особенность работы. Для вычитания/прибавления месяца PHP просто заменяет значение месяца а потом нормализует то, что получилось. Т.е. результат абсолютно такой же как `new DateTime('2016-02-31');`

Comment: Но вообще это неразрешимая в общем виде проблема. Почему для 28 марта и 31 марта «месяц назад» это один тот же день? В общем, надо смотреть по вашей задаче. Я бы сравнил получившийся месяц с исходным и при совпадении брал конец предыдущего месяца

Comment: Я конечно нашел workaround для этого:

    $date->sub(new DateInterval('P'.$date->format('t').'D'));

Но мне кажется крайне странным поведение по умолчанию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После долгих размышлений над тем что сказал [@Alexey Ten](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190728/alexey-ten), и проанализировав то, как работают другие продукты с датами, остановился на том, что мне (в моей задаче) гораздо ближе то как это происходит в PostgreSQL, а именно:

```
psql> select '2016-03-31'::date - 'P1M'::interval;
    ?column?       
---------------------
2016-02-29 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

Соответственно, я написал функцию для этого:

```
function subMonth (DateTime $dateTime, $num = 1) {
    $day       = $dateTime->format('j');
    $month     = $dateTime->format('n');
    $year      = $dateTime->format('Y');
    while ($num > 0) {
        if (1 == $month) {
            --$year;
            $month = 12;
        }
        else {
            --$month;
        }
        $days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
        $dateTime->setDate($year, $month, ($day > $days) ? $days : $day);
        --$num;
    }
    return $dateTime;
}
```

Соответственно что должно получится:

```
echo subMonth(new DateTime('2015-03-31'), 1)->format('Y-m-d'), "\n"; # 2015-02-28
echo subMonth(new DateTime('2016-03-31'), 1)->format('Y-m-d'), "\n"; # 2016-02-29
echo subMonth(new DateTime('2016-03-30'), 1)->format('Y-m-d'), "\n"; # 2016-02-29
echo subMonth(new DateTime('2016-03-29'), 1)->format('Y-m-d'), "\n"; # 2016-02-29
echo subMonth(new DateTime('2016-05-31'), 1)->format('Y-m-d'), "\n"; # 2016-04-30
echo subMonth(new DateTime('2016-05-31'), 2)->format('Y-m-d'), "\n"; # 2016-03-31
echo subMonth(new DateTime('2016-05-31'), 3)->format('Y-m-d'), "\n"; # 2016-02-29
```

Получилось несколько не оптимально, но делает то, что мне нужно в конкретном случае.

Answer (score 0):

Видел решение задачи для +1 месяца... можно по аналогии сделать для -1.

```
function dateAfterMonth($m=1,$d=1,$y=1970)
{
    if($m == 12){
        return strtotime("+1 month",mktime(0,0,0,$m,$d,$y));
    }

    ++$m;
    while(true){
        if(checkdate($m,$d,$y)){
           break;
        }
        --$d;
    }
    return mktime(0,0,0,$m,$d,$y);
}
```